# host process for windows cpu 40-50% when used with hosts file

Tags: hosts-file, dns-cache

I can't run dnsclient because host process for windows cpu 40-50% when
used with hosts file, my laptop works fine with an empty hosts file and
when it is disabled, but I want to run it with a hosts file that is
around 2mb, the entries are 67,000 approximately, should they get in the
dns cache? well, I waited, I  run flushdns too, but cpu wasn't getting lower

Comment: Hi Patrick, it's not clear exactly what you are trying to accomplish here. Please can you make sure your question is clearly defined from the information about your setup.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the hosts file is just searched linearly. 
The code was never optimized to convert it to a hash table or a tree,
or transfer it into DNS, because nobody ever expected people
to have a host file that is anywhere near as big as 2 MB. 
DNS and hosts file are parallel mechanisms; they won’t interact.

You should probably just convert your hosts information into DNS format.

Comment: I was using a much larger hosts file before, around 7mb, without problems, but with dns client service disabled, lately I wanted to switch it on in because I found a utility to monitor dns requests allowed and blocked, which needs dns client running in order to work, anyway, how can I switch my entries to dns format? is it easy?